# How to check if workbench is active from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am completely new to Eclipse Plug-in Development and developing an Eclipse plug-in by following simple examples. I have a requirement to perform some business logic based on whether the user is not in the current Eclipse workbench.

I am trying the following code

```java
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWindowListener(new IWindowListener() {
        .........

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(IWorkbenchWindow arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            .......
        }
     });
```

But the method `windowDeactivated` gets called even if any wizard/dialog is opened. I tried many ways but could not get the proper solution.

Kindly provide a solution as I am completely stuck and the entire project is based on getting solution for this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'user is not in the current eclipse workbench'?

Comment: @greg-449 The user is the developer who is using the eclipse workbench for coding. The plugin that I am developing has a new menu and after selection of that menu, I want my developer to be notified before he/she switches(or minimizes) the eclipse window to any other application on their machine.

Comment: @Jayalakshmi I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the below solution is not advised to be used because of maintenance and  performance issues, I used the following solution to solve the problem.

Kindly let me know if any better solution is available.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().
 getShell().getDisplay().addFilter 
     (SWT.FocusOut,new WindowDisplayListener());

public class WindowDisplayListener implements Listener{

@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {

 //using a similar logic as provided by @Rüdiger Herrmann in the above post.
 Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().
                       getShell().getDisplay().getActiveShell();

  if(shell == null) //code for window inactive.
  }
  }
```

This solution has a small problem. The shell comes as null whenever the user opens a file browser dialog from any of the wizards in eclipse. For eg: If the user opens file browser for importing an existing project the shell becomes null.

Please let me know if any other solution is available.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that your business logic should depend on whether the workbench is active or not.

If you are new to Eclipse plug-in development, take some time to get acquainted with with the concepts.

If you still think you need to know whether the workbench is active you can check if any of its shells are active.

```java
boolean isActive() {
  Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
  return display.getActiveShell() != null;
}
```

`getActiveShell()` returns the currently active `Shell`, or `null` if no shell of the display is active.